# How do I change the HTML code to fit the text?

Tags: html

Here's how it is now:

[image]

```
<pre>

    <li class="list-group-item node-w0 node-selected" data-nodeid="1" style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#428bca;">
    <div class="indent"></div>
    <div class="icon glyphicon"></div>

    <div class="icon node-icon none">
    </div>Прочие Блоки питания красивые умные самые лучшие</li>

</pre>
```

How to align the text of a category whose name is transferred to a new line? Need to draw a table?

Comment: how did you do the indentation to the others?? You can simply add `padding-left` to that containing cell, and `text-align: left`

Comment: Please provide minimal working example here if the problem is more complex

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be using `text-indent` somewhere, which causes to indent just the first line. Use `padding-left` on the box needed instead of `text-indent`.